# People picker not finding FBA users

Tags: people-picker, forms-authentication

I have implemented a custom Membership and Role provider based on this reference:

https://blog.sharedove.com/adisjugo/index.php/2011/01/05/writing-a-custom-membership-provider-and-using-it-for-fba-forms-based-authentication-in-sharepoint-2010-from-the-scratch/

After deploying and configuring, the people picker in the central admin is able to find/resolve the FBA users.  I am also able to log in based on an FBA user, but when using the people picker in the web application, the FBA users are not found.  All the methods in the provider log a message to a text file and based on this, it doesn't seem like the provider is called at all when using the people picker in the web application.

The people picker will also find "All Users (customprovider)" and "All Users (Windows)".

Just wondering if anyone has any ideas on what I might have missed?

Answer (score 0):

this was my bad, turned out to be a permission issue on the text file I was writing to.  gonna delete this post.